# How can I get the enum values from a mongoose schema?

Tags: mongoose

This is my scheme:

```
  var documentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    'facts': [{
      'type': { type: String, required: true, uppercase: true, enum: ['TEXT'], default: 'TEXT'},
      'label': { type: String },
      'value': { type: String }
    }],

    'type': { type: String, required: true, uppercase: true, enum: ['TEXT', 'MARKDOWN', 'JSON'], default: 'TEXT'},

    'lastModified': { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
    'created': { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
  }, {
    versionKey: 'version'
  });
  var DocumentModel = mongoose.model('Document', documentSchema);
```

I can get enums with:

```
DocumentModel.schema.path('type').enumValues,
```

But not with:

```
DocumentModel.schema.path('facts.type').enumValues,
```

I get *TypeError: Cannot read property 'enumValues' of undefined*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Since `facts` is an array with an embedded schema you will need to access that schema first and then you can get the enum values in the same manner you did with `type`.

```
DocumentModel.schema.path('facts').schema.path('type').enumValues
```

Answer (score 3):

Since facts is an object array, you need to get enumValues like the following:

```
DocumentModel.schema.path('facts.0.type').enumValues
```